# How to import R datasets with the same name

Tags: r, import, load

I have three dataset saved in R format A.RData, B.RData, C.RData (each of the size of ~2Gb). Each of the files contains three variables X, Y, Z.

I can not load A.RData and B.RData without first renaming the variables. As the datasets are big these steps:

```
load("A.RData")
A = list(X=X,Y=Y,Z=Z)
rm(X,Y,Z)

load("B.RData")
B = list(X=X,Y=Y,Z=Z)
rm(X,Y,Z)
```

take some time.

Is there a way to import the data from A.RData directly in a list A, without having to make copies of the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.

```
A <- new.env()
load('A.RData', envir=A)
A <- as.list(A)
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. I have one doubt, when running the as.list function the variables are copied or referenced?

Comment: They're copied. If this is problematic, you could consider using environments instead of lists. Environments are basically unordered lists. You can access the elements with `$` and there is even an `eapply` for applying functions over the environment.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I am getting now into R documentation to understand what environments are. Is this a general way to have things passed by reference, rather than copying? As you can imagine, when working with large datasets it helps a lot being able to work on the same object rather than having to copy it eery time!

Comment: Sort of..., but look up reference classes in R.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by Matthew Plourde is the way to go. In future, you can avoid these problems if you save your data with `saveRDS` (not `save`).

The function `saveRDS` saves a single object. For example:

```
X <- 1
Y <- 2
Z <- 3

# put the objects in a list
mylist <- list(X, Y, Z)

# save the list
saveRDS(mylist, file = "myfile.rds")
rm(X, Y, Z, mylist) # remove objects (not necessary)

# load the list
newlist <- readRDS("myfile.rds")
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 3
```

In contrast to `save`, the name of the object is *not* stored. Hence, you can assign the result of `readRDS` to another name. Note that you have to put all variables in *one* list.

Comment: mmm.. this sounds interesting.. just out of curiosity, would saveRDS and readRDS allow me to import only one or two of the variables rather than all three?

Comment: @eroeurbano No, because `saveRDS` allows you to save one object only. Of course, you can still create multiple files, each containing an object.

Comment: I guess I will have to switch to some other format like matlab style hdf5 or something similar. Thanks for your answer, it's been helpful!